# Multiple Image upload and save to Database

Tags: php

Back again! So I'm trying to upload multiple images to a server and save the path and corresponding stock number in the database. Currently I have the car details, $sqlcarinsert, working and inserting into the relevant database, forsale.

The issue arises when I try save all of the image details. I have the images being given new names and uploading to the server but not being inputted into the database with the stockID, which links it to the advert, as well as the filepath. Along with this only one of the files is being inputted into the database not say all three that uploaded to the server. Is this possible to do?

Need anything else let me know I shall try my best to provide!

P.S Yes I know prepared statements, shoody code etc etc..

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['add'])){

include '../Login-System/db.php';

$make = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['Make']);
$model = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['Model']);
$variant = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['Variant']);
$year = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['Year']);
$mileage = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['Mileage']);
$fuel = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['Fuel']);
$doors = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['Doors']);
$trans = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['transmission']);
$enginesize = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['Enginesize']);
$price = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['Price']);
$description = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['description']);

$sqlcarinsert = "INSERT INTO forsale (make, model, variant, year, mileage, fuel, doors, trans, enginesize, price, description) VALUES ('$make','$model','$variant','$year','$mileage','$fuel','$doors','$trans','$enginesize','$price','$description');";


//Image Upload

//Find next StockID (Surely not, right?)
$sql = "SELECT * FROM forsale ;";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($result);   
$stockID = $rowcount + 1;



if(!empty($_FILES['files']['name'][0])){

    $files = $_FILES['files'];

    //File Extensions allowed
    $allowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png');

    foreach ($files['name'] as $position => $file_name) {
        $file_tmp = $files['tmp_name'] [$position];
        $file_size = $files['size'] [$position];
        $file_error = $files['error'] [$position];

        //Get file extension
        $FileExt = explode('.', $file_name);
        $endext = end($FileExt);
        $fileActualExt = strtolower($endext);

        if (in_array($fileActualExt, $allowed)) {
        //Checks for Errors in uploading
            if ($file_error === 0) {

                include '../Login-System/db.php';

                //New name to remove possibilities of duplicates
                $fileNameNew = uniqid('', true).".".$fileActualExt ;
                $FileDestination = '../Photos/forsale/'.$fileNameNew;
                //Upload to Designated folder with name
                move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $FileDestination);
                //Insert into forsaleimg
                $sqlimginsert = "INSERT INTO forsaleimg (StockID, FileDestination) VALUES ('$stockID','$FileDestination');";

                mysqli_query($conn, $sqlimginsert);




            } else {
                header("Location: ../salelist.php?upload=error");
                exit();
            }
        }
    }   
}

mysqli_query($conn, $sqlcarinsert);
header("Location: ../salelist.php?added=".$make);
exit();


} else {
header("Location: ../salelist.php?add=notlcicked");
exit();
}
```

Comment: If your file name extension isn't allowed, it will just skip over it, and not alert the user at all of what is happening.

Comment: Yeah I’m going to add that once I know it works, the main page says what extensions are allowed :)